# How to fix the empty space between Logo and Navigation Menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

This is the Live Demo of my header section, what can I do to fix the empty space between the logo and navigation menu?

I want both the `image` and `.nav` to come close towards each other, not one to lean towards the other so that the empty space outside both is the same.

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 10px 100px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  padding: 8px 12px;
}

.nav .logo {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <img class="logo" src="https://santabanta.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/vbes-2-1.png" alt="">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Classes & Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Kids & Family</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Workshop</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Training</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the justify-content from the `nav`:

```
.nav {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   /* justify-content: space-between; */
   margin: 10px 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried and changed some code of CSS and it looks cool!

https://codepen.io/Ravi_chitroda/pen/LYapMPY

```css
.nav {
  display         : flex;
  align-items     : center;
  justify-content : space-arround;
  margin          : 10px 20px;
  }
ul {
  display    : flex;
  list-style : none;
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
  }
ul li {
  padding : 8px 8px;
  }
.nav .logo {
  width   : 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @abasahed pointed out

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*justify-content: space-between;*/
  margin: 10px 100px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  padding: 8px 12px;
}

.nav .logo {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <img class="logo" src="https://santabanta.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/vbes-2-1.png" alt="">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Classes & Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Kids & Family</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Workshop</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Training</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the codepen link

https://codepen.io/zsaleem/pen/QWowGVg

Answer (score 0):

To get the required result, the value of the margin property in the "nav" class CSS rule should be changed as follows:

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just use `justify-content : space-around;` instead of `justify-content : space-between;`